# ¿En que función del AppDelegate debo poner el código principal?

Tags: swift, swift2

Estoy haciendo una app, en la que necesito que antes de que se inice tengo que gestionar una serie de valores de configuración de la app como colores, textos y cual va a ser la vista principal.

El problema es que me aparece una pantalla en negro antes de que se inice la app, por lo que creo que no lo estoy poniendo en el buen sitio. El código lo tengo en la función `applicationDidBecomeActive`

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        /*AQUI TENGO TODO MI CÓDIGO*/
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

buenos días. La pantalla en negro que te aparece es el PreLoad de la APP. no se puede quitar. Solo puedes cambiarlo y poner a lo mejor una imagen o algo que sea estático.

Para hacer algo de carga previo a iniciar las vistas te explico:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    //Aquí haces los pasos previos a iniciar la vista.

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    if let window = self.window{

        window.rootViewController = ViewController() //Inicia la vista

    }

    return true
}
```

Espero que haya quedado bien explicado.
Puedes ver códigos en Swift 2.0+ y Objective-C en mi [Github](https://github.com/alvaroroyo)

Comment: He puesto las dos primeras lineas en mi código pero me sale este error: `Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch`

Comment: Para hacerlo así no puedes usar Storyboard. Tienes que usar un ViewController propio. En caso de que estés usando Storyboards omite todas las líneas que están escritas menos el return y simplemente haz lo que quieras cargar previamente en ese método.

Comment: Gracias @Alvaro y como puedo hacer para añadir una imagen antes??

Comment: En el StoryBoard llamado: **LaunchScreen.storyboard**
Ahí puedes añadir el logo de tu APP o lo que necesites. Recuerda que ese StoryBoard no tiene ViewController simplemente vale para poner una imagen o darle un color de fondo y esas cosas. @AlbertoMier

Comment: Genial gracias @AlvaroRoyo

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes poner en esta función:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

Pero creo que lo que necesitas es editar el `launch screen`, ahí puedes usar para editar esa pantalla negra.

Si lo que necesitas es carga valores en la función del `appdelegate`